# Форматирование текста при выводе из БД в вид (Laravel)

Tags: html, laravel, view

Есть проблема.

Есть текст, который вводиться в textarea и сохраняется в бд. Он может быть любой длины, с переносами и т д. В бд все сохраняется корректно с переносами

Пример:

```
Привет
Как дела?
```

При рендеринге в виде выводит:

```
Привет Как дела?
```

То есть переносы пропали.
Так же слишком длинный текст просто вылазит за пределы тега

и не переноситься вниз. Тут скорее всего проблема в верстке.

В тег p текст попадает с разрывами строки, а вижу по факту другое.

Comment: А в <pre> нормально?

Comment: да, форматирование переносов в pre нормально.

Comment: в блейде надо выводить не
{{ $text }}

,а 
{!! $text !!} 

такой формат вывода не будет резать спецсимволы

Comment: Я так и вывожу. Не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла функция nl2br($data) ...

Answer (score 0):

Так чтоб HTML отобразил переносы стоки ему тэги 
 нужны. Можно легко проверить накидав простенькую HTML'ку и сделать несколько переносов. Чтобы из textarea сохранить в БД, а потом с теми же переносами вывести на страницу нужно символы переноса строки заменить на соответствующие HTML-тэги (что-то типа `str_replace('\r\n', '<br>', $string)` но не уверен что это лучшее решение). Ещё можно при сохранении делать `htmlspecialchars`, а при выводе `htmlspecialchars_decode`.

Comment: Не работает ни то ни другое решение. Думаю тут проблема с верстке

Comment: Есть ещё вот такая чудестная функция: [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: Ею уже и воспользовался

Comment: Видимо nl2br помогла? По сути она делает то же самое что str_replace, только учитывает все возможные сочетания символов перевода строки (в разных системах это разные символы - \r\n, \n\r, \n и \r)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй `{! $text !}`. По умолчанию конструкция `{{ }}` применяет к содержимому PHP-функцию `htmlentities`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.message_css p {
white-space: pre-line;
/*word-wrap: break-word;*/
/*word-break: break-word;*/
}
```

а там как хотите редактируйте

Comment: Вопрос задан почти 2 года назад.